# Is it possible to get bytecode from the evm in golang?

Tags: evm, golang, bytecode

Imagine this scenario, I have a contract that has a function where I call with runtime.Call().

But this function returns an address of a newly created contract, but not the bytecode as runtime.Create does.

How would I access that bytecode?

Thanks!!

Comment: eth_getcode is invokable over RPC or IPC.

Comment: Yeah, but I am woking directly to the evm creating a genesis file. So I need to get all that data included in a genesis. So I dont have access from outside of the blockchain, because it is not even instantiate. But this gives me a good idea, I can review how that eth_getcode is implemented in the lowlevel. Thanks!

Comment: You can use geth to init a chain with your genesis, and then `geth dump 0` to dump the genesis block state trie, which will contain the code and balances for every account

Comment: what bytecode ??? the bytecode of the contract? it is part of the transaction, a field called `extra data`, also called `input` when evm.Call() is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! Use the client `CodeAt` method of the `ethclient` package to read the bytecode of a deployed smart contract. Here's a full example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54")
    bytecode, err := client.CodeAt(context.Background(), contractAddress, nil) // nil is latest block
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(bytecode)) // 60806...10029
}
```

It'll be the same result as seen on [etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x147b8eb97fd247d06c4006d269c90c1908fb5d54#code)